# Yii bootstrap grid: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: yii, twitter-bootstrap

This:

```
$gridDataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider(array(
    array('id'=>1, 'firstName'=>'Mark', 'lastName'=>'Otto', 'language'=>'CSS'),
    array('id'=>2, 'firstName'=>'Jacob', 'lastName'=>'Thornton', 'language'=>'JavaScript'),
    array('id'=>3, 'firstName'=>'Stu', 'lastName'=>'Dent', 'language'=>'HTML'),
));


 $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.BootGridView', array(
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'dataProvider'=>$gridDataProvider,
    'template'=>"{items}",
    'columns'=>array(
        array('name'=>'id', 'header'=>'#'),
        array('name'=>'firstName', 'header'=>'First name'),
        array('name'=>'lastName', 'header'=>'Last name'),
        array('name'=>'language', 'header'=>'Language'),
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.BootButtonColumn',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 50px'),
        ),
    ),
));
```

is returning:

### Trying to get property of non-object

Menu, buttons (and everything else) works fine.

Comment: Going to need a little more to go on than that. What line is it saying the error is on? It usually means one of your objects has mistakenly been set to NULL, true, false, integer or something else somewhere along the way.

Comment: 60         $url = isset($button['url']) ? $this->evaluateExpression($button['url'], array('data'=>$data, 'row'=>$row)) : '#';

Comment: You'll need to update your question with the first couple of lines of the stack trace from the error plus the code around the main line of the error and any relevant variables. about line 50 - 65 of bootstrap.widgets.BootButtonColumn would help for a start

Answer (score 1):

This hapens because the example uses CArrayDataProvider to populate the grid. 
When you get inside BootButton (the class that generates this column) to see what runs through it, you will see that it is trying to get the primaryKey property from dataprovider, but there is no such property, as the data is of array type.

You have to pass a CActiveDataProvider for your grid, if you plan to use buttons with it.

So try to use like this:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.BootGridView', array(
        'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'template'=>"{items}{pager}",
        'filter'=>$model,...
```

Where  $model is a CActiveRecord passed to the view by your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the code you got in this class -- bootstrap.widgets.BootButtonColumn
But whatever it is, this is a what is causing the issue. 
Make sure you have the full action of each button defined, in order to avoid this issue.

what I mean is, for every button in the button column set the url as --

```
'$this->grid->controller->createUrl("action_name", array("param_name" => "param_value"))'
```

this should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by the Button Column missing variables
It should be

```
array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.BootButtonColumn',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 50px'),
                            'viewButtonUrl'=>null,
                            'updateButtonUrl'=>null,
                            'deleteButtonUrl'=>null,
    ),
```

//[reposted from here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/23982-extension-bootstrap/page__st__140__p__138625#entry138625)